# ASP.Net Core cookie authentication logged in but not authenticated

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, cookie-authentication

We are using simple cookie authentication in a ASP.Net Core webapp. The login has worked for almost 3 months now. Then suddenly, a problem started appearing.

This is how I setup authentication in Startup.cs:

```
private void ConfigureAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
{            
    var configurationService = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IConfigurationService>();
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options => {                
        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/AccessDenied";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double.Parse(configurationService.Get("CookieTimeout").Result.Value));
        options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Logout";
    });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("KeyUsers",
            authBuilder =>
            {
                authBuilder.RequireRole("KeyUsers");
            });
        options.AddPolicy("Admins",
            authBuilder =>
            {
                authBuilder.RequireRole("Admins");
            });
        options.AddPolicy("Users",
            authBuilder =>
            {
                authBuilder.RequireRole("Users");
            });
    });
}
```

Here is how I actually log in:

```
var role = await _roleRepository.Read(user.RoleId);

var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserId.ToString()),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.EmailAddress),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.CWID),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Description)
};

ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");
ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

await httpContext.SignInAsync(principal);

_logger.LogInformation("A user with the following cwid entered the correct password: {0}", cwid);

user.FailedLoginAttempts = 0;
await _userRepository.Update(user);


return LoginResult.Successful;
```

So basically, after the user entered the correct credentials, I log them in using the above code. They should then be redirected to a landing page for logged in users. This has worked fine for 2-3 months but now, for some reason, when they get to the landing page, they are immediately redirected again to the login page, meaning that they are not actually logged in. Strangely, I only have this problem on one browser (new Edge), when I try it using another (Chrome), it works. So I think that there must be something wrong with how the authentication cookie is set in the browser but I am not sure. Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Since you said it's been working for 3 months, was this working in an older version of Edge? Also, have you confirmed that it's the version of Edge you have installed? It's strange that it's only working for Chrome so preliminary debugging into the symptoms of your problem might prove to be useful before a deep dive into code

Comment: I investigated the issue some more and found that one of my coworkers had the same symptoms. The only difference is that she had the problem with Chrome and on Edge it worked. So it probably doesn't have anything to do with either Chrome nor Edge specifically. Still wasn't able to get to the bottom of it, though it hasn't happened again.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of your web app? If you do, it may be a data-protection related problem

Comment: Nope, there are 3 webapps running on IIS 10/Server 2019. The only thing they share is access to the database where all the accounts are stored. A probably cause is that maybe IIS "hung" because the server we used is pretty old with sub-par specs for a server. Another symptom that would support this theory is that our webapps (all 3 of them) stop responding every week and we have to restart the server for them to start working again.